# NGINX => serve several applications on a single host name with sub-uris

Tags: nginx

I'd like to serve several applications from the same server, reversed-proxied through nginx. I'd like these applications to be available through a single domain name with sub-uris.

e.g.

`www.mydomain.com/nodejs`
=> caught by nginx listening to port 80 and served through to a node.js app running on port 3001

`www.mydomain.com/rails`
=> caught by nginx listening to port 80 and served through to a rails app running on port 3002

My first stab is to start with two upstreams:

```
# /etc/nginx/sites-available/mydomain.com

upstream nodejs {
  server 127.0.0.1:3001;
}

upstream rails {
  server 127.0.0.1:3002;
}

server {
  listen 80 default deferred;

  # What do I put here so that
  # mydomain.com/nodejs is proxied to the nodejs upstream and
  # mydomain.com/rails  is proxied to the rails  upstream ???
}
```

Does anyone know this or point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about:

```
upstream nodejs {
    server 127.0.0.1:3001;
}

upstream rails {
    server 127.0.0.1:3002;
}

server {
    listen 80;  

    location /nodejs {
        proxy_pass         http://nodejs;
        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    location /rails {
        proxy_pass         http://rails;
        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

}
```

or shortly:

```
server {   
    listen 80;     

    location /nodejs {
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:3001;
        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    location /rails {
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:3002;
        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

}
```

?

Most of the proxy directives are optional (you probably just need `proxy_pass` and `proxy_redirect`) but useful.

Comment: thanks for answering! Although with this configuration, it seems to only serve the first of the two locations whether I am on mydomain.com/nodejs or mydomain.com/rails and can't server files in that app because they don't have the sub-uri (e.g. they try to serve mydomain.com/myjavascriptasset.js instead of mydomain.com/nodejs/myjavascriptasset.js). Ideally I'd like the applications to work without being aware of the sub-uri (if possible...)

Comment: I had a typo. It does proxy mydomain.com/nodejs to the node.js app, and mydomain.com/rails to the rails app with this config. The only problem is that if these apps serve an html page with a script tag referencing an asset named myjavascriptasset.js, the files are a 404 because they do not include the sub-uri (e.g. they try to serve mydomain.com/myjavascriptasset.js instead of mydomain.com/nodejs/myjavascriptasset.js). Ideally I'd like the applications to work without being aware of the sub-uri, any idea?

Comment: Well the assets are probably referenced from HTML or CSS, so the browser (not rails app or nodejs) makes a request directly to your webserver which does the proxying. This webserver has to serve the assets, and with current config it simply doesn't know about any assets. You need to serve them separately, perhaps you could instrument your app to prefix the URLs? E.g. /rails/myjavascript.js and then use `try_files` directive in Nginx to first try assets and only then redirect to the upstream ?

Comment: Indeed, they are referenced from HTML and CSS with a source url being "/myassets.js" which prompts the browser to request "http://mydomain.com/myassets.js". I guess there is no other solution but to modify the applications so that they reference assets as "/nodejs/myassets.js" or to use sub-domains instead. After a first connection from a given ip is made to say "mydomain.com/nodejs", there is no way for nginx to rewrite the uri for all subsequents requests and add the "/nodejs" portion?

Comment: I ended up using subdomains combined with a map statement to forward to the right upstream. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @olivoil What do you mean by subdomains and map? Can you paste some code snippet here?

Answer (score 0):

About the question ,css、js、images files are missed , you can do like this,

if you  use express framework。
you need add this code line

```
app.enable('trust proxy');
```

this value 'trust proxy' default value is  disable.